# Why getting different Specificity results on ConfusionMatrix for same ranger model on same train datain R caret?

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, r-caret, confusion-matrix

I am new in `R` and using caret to implement `ml`. I am trying a binary `classification` - `yes/no` problem of **Bank Marketing Response**  from **UCI**.

**Issue**: on training model on `train` data, the model displays max `Specificity` as `0.4974` but when I plot a `ConfusionMatrix` on same `train` data I get `0.9684` `Specificity`. Such high difference of `Specificity` in `model summary` & `confusion matrix` looks strange and not able to understand. (As this is `imbalanced` data so considering `Specificity` for `yes` class over the `accuracy`).

Appreciate any help or cause explanation for same

[image]

## Code below for reference:

Downloading data from UCI

(unable to to download by R code but manually it gets downloaded from link)

```
url <- "https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00222/bank-additional.zip"

temp <- tempfile()
download.file(url,temp)

data <- read.table(unz(temp, "bank-additional.csv"))
unlink(temp)
```

### Train/Test

```
library(tidyverse)
library(caret)

set.seed(123)

data_split_index <- createDataPartition(data$y, p = 0.7, list = FALSE)


train <- data[data_split_index,]
test <- data[-data_split_index,]


y_train = subset(train, select = y)
X_train = subset(train, select = -y)


# Data imbalance
table(y_train)
table(y_test)
```

### Outlier Treatment

```
# Outlier capping function
outlier_cap <- function(x, na.rm = TRUE){
  
  upper_cap = quantile(x, 0.99, na.rm = T)
  lower_cap = quantile(x, 0.01, na.rm = T)
  
  x[x > upper_cap] = upper_cap
  x[x < lower_cap] = lower_cap
  
  x <- x
}

# capping outliers
train <- train %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, outlier_cap)
```

### One Hot Encoding

```
pp_dummy <- dummyVars(y ~ ., data = train)

train <- predict(pp_dummy, newdata = train)
train <- data.frame(train)

test <- predict(pp_dummy, newdata = test)
test <- data.frame(test)
```

### Data Pre Processing

```
pp_standardize <- preProcess(train, method = c("center","scale"))

train <- predict(pp_standardize, newdata = train)



pp_range <- preProcess(train, method = c("range"))

train <- predict(pp_range, newdata = train)
```

### append y to train

```
train$y <- Y_train # as.factor(Y)
```

### tuning

```
fitCtrl <- trainControl(
  method = "cv",
  # repeats = 5,
  number = 10,
  savePredictions = "final",
  classProbs = TRUE,
  summaryFunction = twoClassSummary
)
```

### Model Ranger py

```
set.seed(123)

system.time(
  model_ranger_py <-  train(pull(y) ~ cons.conf.idx+contact.telephone+duration+emp.var.rate+job.self.employed+month.jun+month.mar+month.may+month.nov+poutcome.success+previous,
                            data = train,
                            metric = "Spec",
                            method = "ranger",
                            trControl = fitCtrl)
)
```

### Issue in results of below two lines of Codes

```
model_ranger_py
```

```
confusionMatrix(predict(model_ranger_py, newdata = train), pull(train$y))
```

## (UPDATE)

Getting even weird results between `train` & `test` data comparison

#### CM train

```
confusionMatrix(predict(model_ranger_py, newdata = train), pull(train$y))

################################ output ################################
Confusion Matrix and Statistics

          Reference
Prediction   no  yes
       no  2562   10
       yes    6  306
                                             
               Accuracy : 0.9945             
                 95% CI : (0.991, 0.9968)    
    No Information Rate : 0.8904             
    P-Value [Acc > NIR] : <0.0000000000000002
                                             
                  Kappa : 0.9714             
                                             
 Mcnemar's Test P-Value : 0.4533             
                                             
            Sensitivity : 0.9977             
            Specificity : 0.9684
```

```
plot_pred_type_distribution(df_train)
```

[image]

#### CM test

```
confusionMatrix(predict(model_ranger_py, newdata = test), pull(y_test)) 

################################ output ################################
Confusion Matrix and Statistics

          Reference
Prediction  no yes
       no  166   8
       yes 934 127
                                             
               Accuracy : 0.2372             
                 95% CI : (0.2138, 0.262)    
    No Information Rate : 0.8907             
    P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 1                  
                                             
                  Kappa : 0.0229             
                                             
 Mcnemar's Test P-Value : <0.0000000000000002
                                             
            Sensitivity : 0.1509             
            Specificity : 0.9407
```

```
plot_pred_type_distribution(df_test)
```

[image]

Comment: `model_ranger_py` outputs the metric based on resampling (data the model has not seen - test error), while `predict(model_ranger_py, newdata = train)` generates predictions from data the model was fit on (train error)

Comment: @missuse I am not sure what exactly is resampling data, I think you are referring them as each fold of cross validation. Even in that case it looks like huge gap in performance. Next when I am `validating` this model on test data I am getting a completely opposite results: `Sensitivity : 0.1509`, `Specificity : 0.9407`. Code: `confusionMatrix(predict(model_ranger_py, newdata = test), pull(y_test))`. I am really surprised by the results from this model. Adding an `update` to the original post.

Comment: @missuse adding more to above I don't know why I get probabilities on `test data` in more `discrete` sort of values rather than continuous. I noticed this in some previous model as well. I am not sure but it could be because of `cross validation`. Referring to `chart` produced from `plot_pred_type_distribution(df_test)` code in updated part of post.